# How to show that the first derivative is bounded in a function

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, bounded-variation

\begin{equation}
y=\arccos\left( -\frac{1}{2\left(Dr^{\dfrac {|\sin(2x+\theta)|}{M\sin x\sqrt{A+2B\cos(2x+\theta)}}}+1\right)} \right)  \nonumber
\end{equation}

How to show in above function the first derivative is bounded?

$\theta,D,M,A,B,r$ are constants but they have bounds too

$\theta<2\pi/3$,

$A,B,M,D>0$

$1\leq r \leq 2$

Also for the variables

$y \geq 0$ and $\pi/2 \leq x \leq 2\pi/3$

Comment: Can you possibly re-typeset the equation to make it more readable?  Maybe make the fraction inside the "arccos" have the form "-1/[stuff]" instead of using "\frac"?

Comment: @StefanSmith I edited it (frac->dfrac) to make it more readable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does a problem like this come from?